# Sponge cake: how the proportions of the ingredients change the result

Tags: eggs, cake, sugar, flour, sponge-cake

The common recipe (at least in Italy) for sponge cake is:

- total weight of eggs (yolks + whites) = X
- sugar = flour = 2/3 X

I'm aware that the ratio of the ingredients affect the final result. For example, sugar in puff pastry controls the crunchiness while butter friability.

What are the roles of sugar and flour in sponge cake?